# fedora Jconsole location

Tags: java, fedora

Where can I find the Jconsole in fedora?
I have installed java and jdk.
I have grepped the HD for jconsole but i could not find it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try updatedb then locate ? Does the command jconsole do anything?

Comment: 1. yes, no results (sudo locate -i "jconsole" / | grep "jconsole"). 
2. jconsole - command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running:
 yum provides */jconsole

that will tell you what package you need as well as where it's located in the package.